# ListIterator throws "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" Java

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, do-while

I have searched a bit online but either the explanations are way over my head or people actually suggest using an ArrayList to avoid getting an exception.. So i am a wee bit helpless right now. This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayIterator {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<String> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ListIterator<String> simpleIterator = simpleList.listIterator(0);
    static int b = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getInput();
        spellOutput();

    }
    private static void getInput(){
        System.out.println("What do you want to add to your list? You can name five items");
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            String m = scan.nextLine();
            simpleList.add(m);
        }
    }
    private static void spellOutput(){
        System.out.println("Here are the items from your list: ");
        do{
            System.out.println(simpleIterator.next());
        }while(simpleIterator.hasNext());
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine in the `getInput` method and i can output the ArrayList easily via `System.out.println();`. When i use the `spellOut` method however, things go south and i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1009)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:963)
    at ArrayIterator.spellOutput(ArrayIterator.java:28)
    at ArrayIterator.main(ArrayIterator.java:15)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You created iterator.
2. You modified list.
3. You used iterator.

That is why the concurrent exception was thrown. To avoid exception being thrown you should have add items to list only using iterator like that:

```
simpleIterator.add(m)
```

Comment: You are right sir. Well that was easy! Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Iterator is created before getInput() is called.

Here iterator is created from an empty list. It is forbidden to structurally modify (add or remove elements) the collection while iterating (search fail-fast iterator).

Solution - move iterator creation to the spellOutput().

Answer (score 0):

A Concurrent Modification happens when you modify a collection/list/map while another operation is being preformed on that same collection/list/map.

For example

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("yes", "no", "maybe");
 for(String string : list) { //operation 1 - list iteration
     list.add("definitely not"); //operation 2 - add to list -- will throw concurrent modification exception because operation 1 is still pending.
 }
```

For your scenario, to fix this, remove

```
ListIterator<String> simpleIterator
```

as a global variable, and initialize it after you've added your elements to the list from your scanner.

```
private static void spellOutput() {
    ListIterator<String> simpleIterator = simpleList.listIterator(0);
    System.out.println("Here are the items from your list: ");
    do {
        System.out.println(simpleIterator.next());
    } while(simpleIterator.hasNext());
}
```

And there you go, no more concurrent modification exceptions